# main.CRITICAL: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user

Tags: magento2, error, exception

I get this error on my frontend: `An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.`

This is my `exceptions.log`:

```
2017-10-16 14:21:13] main.CRITICAL: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myusername'@xxx.Xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)' in /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129
Stack trace:
#0 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=10.1...', 'myusername', 'password...', Array)
#1 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#2 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(353): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect()
#4 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array)
#7 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array)
#8 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/Db/FetchStrategy/Query.php(21): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array)
#9 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(772): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array)
#10 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(668): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select))
#11 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(572): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->getData()
#12 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(557): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false)
#13 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(820): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load()
#14 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(78): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator()
#15 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(58): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig()
#16 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('')
#17 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get()
#18 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read()
#19 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(212): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read()
#20 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(170): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default')
#21 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...')
#22 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...')
#23 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL)
#24 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/HeaderProvider/Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...')
#25 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply()
#26 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#27 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#28 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/pub/errors/report.php(15): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
#29 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(323): require('/var/sites/v/va...')
#30 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(160): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleGenericReport(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception))
#31 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception))
#32 /var/sites/v/domainm2.co.uk/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#33 {main}
```

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your MySQL connection is failing with "Access denied". This means your MySQL user hasn't been granted permission to the database you are telling it to use.

Try the recommendations here for others with the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353402/access-denied-for-user-testlocalhost-using-password-yes-except-root-user

Try the official MySQL troubleshooting guide on connection problems: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html

2. Your MySQL username and password (part of it, anyway) are in your question. Change them.

Comment: That worked. Yes, didn't realise there was sensitive information there. I have deleted the user now. Thank you.